# QGIS crashes when loading DWG file in Georeferencer

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, dwg

I am trying to use QGIS to georeference a CAD file. I open Raster/Georeferencer and then click on the Open Raster icon. The first time I tried this it warned me that it would only accept DWG R2000 [ACAD1015]. So my colleague has exported from AutoCAD in DWG R2000.

However, as soon as I select this file and click Open, QGIS crashes. I don't believe there is an issue with the file as it opens fine in ArcGIS.

I tried this in 3.22 first and then upgraded to QGIS 3.24. However, I get the same response.

Comment: I suggest you colleague moves the drawing to the correct place using CAD and a local UTM zone. This is highly recommendable when you need to interchange data between CAD and GIS.

Comment: Does QGIS really crash? It shouldn't so crash would be a bug. But does your dwg file contain raster layers? If I try to open a vector dwg with raster georeferencer I get a message "This raster file has no bands and is invalid as raster layer". If you have vector dwg perhaps this blog helps with it https://www.mkrgeo-blog.com/good-solution-to-georeferencing-the-autocad-dwg-drawing-in-qgis-3x/.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed crash - I checked again. It might be an issue with the CAD file but even so it should not crash without a warning. So I will raise a bug report but I didn't want to do that first incase I was perhaps doing something obviously wrong. I see that blog but it doesn't give me an approach that is sufficiently accurate.

Comment: Erik - thanks for the comment. We have tried adding the local UTM zone. However, as far as I can see the CRS information is not transferred in DWG or DXF so QGIS (and ArcGIS) always treat the file as having a local coordinate system and so locate it in the Gulf of Guinea off the coast of Ghana. Do you know of a way to ensure the CAD file gets placed according to a global coordinate?

Comment: Do you have rasters layers in your CAD file https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cad.html or does it contain only vectors https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/dwg.html?

Comment: Ah, no this is the problem. QGIS won't do geolocation on vector graphics yet, although it will be available shortly. It should have given me a warning and not just crashed so there is an open issue. However, I was premature in trying to georeference my CAD export in this way so we can close this question now.

Comment: you can convert dwg to dxf formate first, and then try ti import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the plugin « vector bender »!
I was able to georeference vector layers without problem…

Answer (score 0):

QGIS cannot georeference a vector DWG at present, although vector georeferencing will be available in an upcoming release. The crash should not have happened, however, and is being investigated.